# How to convert a dataframe to combined dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I wanna turn in to dictionary. But problem is that data is repeating and I want it combined. But cause it is the dictionary the last value replaces the value before for the same key of  course. Code for example.

```
df = 
example column a    example column b
a                       2
b                       3
a                       4
c                       5
a                       2
c                       3



my_dict = enzyme_gene.set_index('example column a')['example column b'].to_dict()
```

and I get `my_dict = {'b: 3', 'a: 2', 'c: 3'}` what I would like to get is

```
my_desired_combined_dict = {'a: 2, 4, 2', 'b: 3', 'c: 5, 3'}
```

Comment: You would like to get a dict of strings?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You expected output is not valid `dictionary`.

If need `dictionary of lists` use `groupby` with `list` first:

```
my_dict1 = enzyme_gene.groupby('example column a')['example column b'].apply(list).to_dict()
print (my_dict1)
{'a': [2, 4, 2], 'b': [3], 'c': [5, 3]}
```

Or `groupby` with `join` for strings:

```
my_dict2 = (enzyme_gene.groupby('example column a')['example column b']
                     .apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.astype(str)))
                     .to_dict())
print (my_dict2)
{'a': '2, 4, 2', 'b': '3', 'c': '5, 3'}
```